# Split string values separated by a semicolon using sProc in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, string, stored-procedures, split

I need split this string using `stored Procedure` in `MySQL` 8 version

> "John;Elizabeth;Mark;Zagor;Annie;Lucy;Peter;Robin;Wilson;Tom;Bettie;Myriam;Frankie;Nick;Marilyn"

The string values are separated by a semicolon.

My `sProc` below.

The problem it's in output.

The first name splitted on this string it's `Elizabeth` and not `John`.

Where is it `John`?

All other names are present in output of `sProc`, only `John` is missing...

What am I doing wrong?

```
BEGIN

DECLARE tNameSeries LONGTEXT;
DECLARE t_tNameSeries LONGTEXT;

SET tNameSeries = "John;Elizabeth;Mark;Zagor;Annie;Lucy;Peter;Robin;Wilson;Tom;Bettie;Myriam;Frankie;Nick;Marilyn";

WHILE LOCATE(";",tNameSeries) > 0 DO

SET tNameSeries = REPLACE (tNameSeries, (SELECT LEFT(tNameSeries,LOCATE(";",tNameSeries))),'');

SET t_tNameSeries = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tNameSeries,";",1);

SELECT t_tNameSeries;

END WHILE;

END
```

**update**

Using ths edit `sProc` the output is only `John`

```
BEGIN

DECLARE tNameSeries LONGTEXT;
DECLARE t_tNameSeries LONGTEXT;

SET tNameSeries = "John;Elizabeth;Mark;Zagor;Annie;Lucy;Peter;Robin;Wilson;Tom;Bettie;Myriam;Frankie;Nick;Marilyn";

WHILE LOCATE(";",tNameSeries) > 0 DO

SET t_tNameSeries = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tNameSeries,";",1);

SET tNameSeries = REPLACE (t_tNameSeries, (SELECT LEFT(t_tNameSeries,LOCATE(";",t_tNameSeries))),'');

SELECT tNameSeries;

END WHILE;

END
```

Comment: The replace() removes the first element "John" before you've had a chance to do anything with it.  The replace() should be *after* the substring_index()  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=131fec600fa8314ba83f504806453f8e

Comment: @SOS thanks for reply. I have edit  the `sproc` and move the `replace()` after the `substring_index()`, but in output I have only `John`

Comment: @SOS Okay. I have edit the question. Thanks

Comment: @AKINA the version of MySQL is 8.0.12

Comment: Why does your first code have `SELECT t_tNameSeries;` and your second has `SELECT tNameSeries;`   ??  (note: a missing `_`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(
    CONCAT(
        '["',
        REPLACE(
            "John;Elizabeth;Mark;Zagor;Annie;Lucy;Peter;Robin;Wilson;Tom;Bettie;Myriam;Frankie;Nick;Marilyn",
            ';',
            '","'
            ),
        '"]'
        ),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        id FOR ORDINALITY,
        name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'
        )
    ) jsontable;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=546907fc5c00b7173fa73327fdd97638

Insert it into the SP if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
set @names = 'John;Elizabeth;Mark;Zagor;Annie;Lucy;Peter;Robin;Wilson;Tom;Bettie;Myriam;Frankie;Nick;Marilyn';

select 
   substring_index(substring_index(@names,';',R),';',-1) W 
from (select row_number() over () as R 
      from information_schema.tables) x 
where x.R<=1+length(@names)-length(replace(@names,';',''));
```

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5cc442be9da54d8cbcdbabc58ee37b65

Comment: Clever use of row_number()!